# Two tables MAX DATE

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

Table A has columns account, b, c
Table B has columns account, date

How can I join `WHERE TABLEA.account=TABLEB.account`?

Here is where I'm struggling, I just want to get the rows from TABLE B with MAX(date) per each account on TABLE B.

Comment: Check out `Group By` and `Having` using `MAX`. You should also add the tag for what DBMS you are using, such as SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle...
WITH clause is here just to generate sample data and it is not a part of the answer.
You didn't say what if there are no records in table B matching the ACCT in table A. This is simple solution to give you max date from table B for every account in table A. Regards...

```sql
WITH 
    a AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "ACCT", 'This is B_1' "B", 'This is C_1' "C" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 "ACCT", 'This is B_2' "B", 'This is C_2' "C" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 "ACCT", 'This is B_3' "B", 'This is C_3' "C" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 "ACCT", 'This is B_4' "B", 'This is C_4' "C" FROM DUAL 
        ),
    b AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "ACCT", '2022-02-24' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 "ACCT", '2022-01-01' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 "ACCT", '2022-02-21' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 "ACCT", '2022-02-28' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 "ACCT", '2022-03-24' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 "ACCT", '2022-04-15' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 "ACCT", '2022-05-12' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL            
            SELECT 3 "ACCT", '2022-02-01' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 "ACCT", '2022-01-31' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 "ACCT", '2022-07-01' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 "ACCT", '2022-06-02' "DATE_COL" FROM DUAL 
        )
SELECT a.ACCT "ACCT", Max(b.DATE_COL) "DATE_COL"
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON(b.ACCT = a.ACCT)
GROUP BY a.ACCT
ORDER BY a.ACCT
--
--  R e s u l t
--
--        ACCT DATE_COL 
--  ---------- ----------
--           1 2022-04-15 
--           2 2022-05-12 
--           3 2022-02-21 
--           4 2022-07-01
```